# How to upload an asset using capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control-file teste" style="display: inline" ;="" accept=".pdf">
```

And try

```
attach_file('file','PATH')
```

try too

```
find('form input[type="file"]').set('PATH')
```

but my result was

```
cannot attach file, input[id=file] does not exist (Capybara::FileNotFound)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you've posted is the error message that is returned when the file you are attempting to upload doesn't exist.

The issue with that is that you shouldn't be passing `input[id=file]` as the filename.  I'm not sure what version of Capybara you're using but in current versions `attach_file` is defined as `def attach_file(locator = nil, paths, make_visible: nil, **options)` where the locator is the name, id, or associated label text of the file input, and paths is the full name of the file to be upload (or potentially an array of filenames).  The issue with this is that it doesn't appear that any of the code you've shown could produce the error you're claiming unless you had swapped the arguments, and were incorrectly passing a CSS selector rather than a locator.

Note: Capybara 3.15 with some drivers (should be any JS capable drivers) supports a beta mode for `attach_file` where you don't have to specify the file input but instead just need to interact with whatever a user would do to trigger the file select which can be helpful when attempting to test with UIs that hide the file input elements

```
attach_file 'PATH' do
  click_button 'Select File' # whatever action a user would do to select the file
end
```